# Finding item with the lowest cost in an ArrayList

Tags: java

What I need to do is find the inventory item with the lowest cost from an array list. If there are none, return "N/A". So I can't really figure out how to find the smallest value out of all the inventory item costs. This is what I have so far. My plan was to set cost equal to the first inventory item and cycle through each item checking if it's cost is less but I'm confused on how to do that or if that is even the correct way of doing it.

EDIT: We have not covered for loops yet so I cannot use them. I can only use while loops

```
public InventoryItem itemWithLowestCost() {
    if (inventoryList.size() > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < inventoryList.size()) {
            double cost = inventoryList.get(i).getCost();
            if (cost < )
        }

    }
    else {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

Here is my InventoryItem constructor. I'm not sure if this is needed to understand the above code but here it is anyway

```
public InventoryItem(String descriptionIn, double costIn, double percentDepreciatedIn) {
    description = descriptionIn.trim();
    cost = costIn;
    percentDepreciated = percentDepreciatedIn;
}
```

Comment: Sort the list with a custom `Comparator`, pick the last (or first, depending on the direction the items are sorted) item...If you can't do that, then take a look at `Math.min`

Comment: Iterating over all list is the worst solution... its better sort or use another data structure like tree if you could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by checking the length to be non-zero, then picking the cost of element zero as "tentative best", and comparing it to costs of other elements on the list:

```
if (inventoryList.size() > 0) {
    int best = 0;
    int i  = 1;
    while (i < inventoryList.size()) {
        double cost = inventoryList.get(i).getCost();
        if (cost < inventoryList.get(best).getCost()) {
            best = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return inventoryList.get(best);
} else {
    return "N/A";
}
```

Comment: Make it an `Integer` and initialize it to `null` to start. Then you can make `if (best == null || cost < inventoryList.get(i).getCost())`

Comment: @Denise No, that's the trick - make `best=0`, and start your loop at `1` to avoid the "if it is not set or..." portion of the condition.

Comment: The only problem is we haven't covered for loops so I can't use them, only while loops are allowed.

Comment: @user3261339 You can convert the `for` loop to a `while` loop by moving the declaration `int i = 1` outside the `while`, and then moving the `i++` part to the back of the loop body.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can you explain the loop in detail? I'm having trouble understanding how this loop finds the lowest value

Comment: @user3261339 The loop starts with the knowledge that there is at least one element. (`if` on the first line checks that). This is the element (at index zero) that we designate the "best". Variable `best` stores the index of the best element so far. At each iteration the loop retrieves the next `cost`, and compares it to the cost at the `best` *position*. If the cost at `i` is better, `i` becomes the new `best`. Once the loop is over, `best` contains the index of the item with the best cost.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `O(n)` loop

```
public InventoryItem itemWithLowestCost() {
  int size = (inventoryList == null || inventoryList.isEmpty()) ? 
          0 : inventoryList.size();
  InventoryItem min = (size > 0) ? inventoryList.get(0) : null;
  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    InventoryItem ii = inventoryList.get(i);
    if (ii.getCost() < min.getCost()) min = ii;
  }
  return min;
}
```

*Note*: That you can't return a `String` N/A as an `InventoryItem` instance (so this returns `null`).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a comparitor to sort the inventory by cost, lowest to highets.

```
public InventoryItem itemWithLowestCost(Collection<InventoryItem> inventory) {
  if(inventory != null && !inventory.isEmpty()) {
    Collections.sort(inventory, new Comparator<InventoryItem>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(InventoryItem i1, InventoryItem i2) {
            return i1.getCost() - i2.getCost();
        }
    });
    return inventory.get(0);
  }
  return null;    
}
```